# GPRbuild: relocation truncated to fit R_X86_64

Tags: linker, ada, gnat, gprbuild

I'm dealing with huge global lists in Ada. When building I'm getting the error during linking:
`relocation truncated to fit R_X86_64_PC32` and `link of main.adb failed`.
I saw that GCC has the flag -mcmodel=medium, is there something similar for gprbuild or does anyone has a hint how to deal with huge global lists?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried adding `-mcmodel=medium` to the Ada switches - result, the clang assembler (I’m on macOS) executed an illegal instruction :-(